# Apply a sepia filter to an image

Tags: beginner, image, go

I'm writing a simple function that applies a Sepia filter to an image. My function works, but I'm a beginner gopher. So I would like to know if there is a way to improve the code. I usually code in Javascript, so I have troubles with a strong typed language such as go.

```
// Sepia apply a sepia filter to Image.
func Sepia(pic image.Image) (output *image.RGBA) {

    bounds := pic.Bounds()
    w, h := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y
    rect := image.Rect(0, 0, w, h)
    output = image.NewRGBA(rect)

    for x := bounds.Min.X; x <= w; x++ {
        for y := bounds.Min.Y; y <= h; y++ {
            r, g, b, a := pic.At(x, y).RGBA()
// Part to improve from HERE
            r >>= 8
            g >>= 8
            b >>= 8
            a >>= 8

            r = uint32(math.Min(.393*float64(r)+.769*float64(g)+.189*float64(b), 255))
            g = uint32(math.Min(.349*float64(r)+.686*float64(g)+.168*float64(b), 255))
            b = uint32(math.Min(.272*float64(r)+.534*float64(g)+.131*float64(b), 255))

            newColor := color.RGBA{
                uint8(r),
                uint8(g),
                uint8(b),
                uint8(a),
            }
// to HERE
            output.Set(x, y, newColor)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a way to improve the code.
>
> ```
> // Part to improve from HERE
> r >>= 8
> g >>= 8
> b >>= 8
> a >>= 8
>
> r = uint32(math.Min(.393*float64(r)+.769*float64(g)+.189*float64(b), 255))
> g = uint32(math.Min(.349*float64(r)+.686*float64(g)+.168*float64(b), 255))
> b = uint32(math.Min(.272*float64(r)+.534*float64(g)+.131*float64(b), 255))
>
> newColor := color.RGBA{
>   uint8(r),
>   uint8(g),
>   uint8(b),
>   uint8(a),
> }
> // to HERE
> ```

---

In Go, readability is paramount. I would write:

```
// Part to improve from HERE

rr := float64(r >> 8)
gg := float64(g >> 8)
bb := float64(b >> 8)
aa := a >> 8

newColor := color.RGBA{
    R: uint8(math.Min(.393*rr+.769*gg+.189*bb, 255)),
    G: uint8(math.Min(.349*rr+.686*gg+.168*bb, 255)),
    B: uint8(math.Min(.272*rr+.534*gg+.131*bb, 255)),
    A: uint8(aa),
}

// to HERE
```